# Python OAuth 2.0 embedd Client_secret.json

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a program to mark appointments on google calendare, using python [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) everything works, but the program reads **client_secret.json** and **credential.json** information from plaintext files, while this information should be protected.

I thought about encrypting the files, but how can I perform the **client.flow_from_clientsecrets** procedure by passing the file contents (a string) and not the file itself?

I would like to avoid editing google-api-python-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OAuth2WebServerFlow`:

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

flow_params = {
    'access_type': 'offline',
    'prompt': 'consent'
}

flow_scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.edit",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
]

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    scope=flow_scopes,
    redirect_uri='http://www.redirect_uri.com',
    **flow_params
)
```

Comment: Yes, I basically saw what does run_flow in tools.py it is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth)

Comment: `tools.run_flow()` attempts to open up a browser window to allow the user to authenticate your service.